# Strange subtraction result with PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a project for a client, its a quite simple. But there is one calculation I have to make which is also very simple, its like this example:

```
$a = (49.95 - 24.95);
if ($a == 25.00) {
    echo "TRUE";
}
```

This equals 25.00 right! But no its returning false???

But if I do this, another example similar to a calculation I need:

```
$a = (99.95 - 24.95);
if ($a == 75.00) {
    echo "TRUE";
}
```

Then I get true! Am I going mad, or is this a bug???

Comment: You can **never**, ***ever*** compare floating point values for equality. Google it or wait for someone to post the relevant links. :-)

Comment: This is math... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Obligatory xkcd cartoon: http://www.xkcd.com/217/

Comment: it is related to Maths as I think.

Answer (score 2):

Like you can read in manual, don't compare float directly. Instead use `epsilon`.

```
<?php
$a = 1.23456789;
$b = 1.23456780;
$epsilon = 0.00001;

if(abs($a-$b) < $epsilon) {
    echo "true";
}
```

That's because of the way how PHP stores float internally. You can read about it in manual, eg. here https://www.php.net/float

Comment: Thank you, will not forget next time :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. It's about [float number precision](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). Since float numbers are stored with decimal precision, you can't rely on precise compare operations, like `==` (equality comparison).

Instead you shoult use precision delta and compare floats like:

```
$a = (49.95 - 24.95);
$b = 25;
$delta = 1E-13;

if(abs($a-$b)<$delta)
{
   echo('TRUE');
}
```

In PHP, 1E-13 will be enough for using as precision delta. For very simple explanation, see [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/) guide about float numbers and their representation.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly, I just could not get me head arround why the first example was not working and the second was.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = (49.95 - 24.95);
if ((int)$a == 25) {
    echo "TRUE";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first example there is a float number which is compared to an int number and at the second there is a float number compared to a float number. The difference occurs because of the floating point precision and its not a bug.

To solve this you can define a `d (delta)` number which will be the precision of the calculation

and then you could check if the absolute result of `x-y` will be lower then the precision you defined. Something like this `if(abs(x-y) < d)`